# Heroku github actions Error: Cannot find module /app/build/index.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, github-actions

I was working on CI/CD for a node.js application using heroku and github-actions. However, heroku tries to find ./app/build/server.js instead of ./build/server.js, which is my application starting point, and as a result, an error occurs because that file does not exist.

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "bangba",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon build/index.js",
    "start": "node build/index.js",
    "stop": "pm2 stop index",
    "build:server": "babel src -d build",
    "build:client": "npx webpack --mode=production",
    "dev:server": "nodemon",
    "dev:client": "npx webpack --mode=development -w"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/somn45/Bangba.git"
  },
  "author": "somn45",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/somn45/Bangba/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/somn45/Bangba#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/node": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "connect-mongo": "^4.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "pm2": "^5.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "^12.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.66.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1282.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.4",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "multer-s3": "^2.10.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pug": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

#### heroku-deploy.yml

```yaml
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 12.x
          cache: npm
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build:server
      - run: npm run build:client
      - uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.13.15
        with:
          heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
          heroku_app_name: 'bangmoa'
          heroku_email: 'somn45@gmail.com'
          procfile: 'web: node ./build/index.js'
```

#### server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import path from 'path';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import session from 'express-session';
import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo';

import DB_URL from './db';
import globalRouter from './routers/globalRouter';
import userRouter from './routers/userRouter';
import cafeRouter from './routers/cafeRouter';
import commentRouter from './routers/commentRouter';
import apiRouter from './routers/apiRouter';
import { sessionMiddleware } from './middlewares/sessionMiddleware';

const COOKIE_EXPIRY_TIME = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src', 'views'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: DB_URL }),
    cookie: {
      maxAge: COOKIE_EXPIRY_TIME,
    },
  })
);
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'));
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
app.use('/dist', express.static('dist'));
app.use('/', globalRouter);
app.use('/users', userRouter);
app.use('/cafes', cafeRouter);
app.use('/comments', commentRouter);
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

export default app;
```

There were similar questions from other developers, so I tried adding the procfile attribute, but the error still occurred.